# Windows 10 Connect to Disconnected user session without password as Domain Admin

Tags: domain, domain-controller, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 PC (Virtual Machine) on a domain and a domain user logged in to it (albeit disconnected). This user has started some applications that have caused a massive consumption of network resources - task manager indicates it's a program they are running in Visual Studio.

Now, the user has disconnected from the computer and I've logged in as domain admin to try and see what's going on, but when I go to Task Manager->Users and try to 'Connect' to their session to see what they were up to, I'm prompted for a password which I don't have. As the Domain Administrator I seem to be unable to take control of their session to see what's actually going on. Is there a way around this?

To add; I have considered resetting the users password on the Domain Controller, but I'm not sure that the Windows 10 VM is refreshing from the DC immediately - short of disconnecting the network resources (which I've done) and hoping that waiting a bit and seeing if the Windows 10 VM will query the DC for the new password instead of whatever it has cached locally, I'm pretty much out of ideas...

Any help appreciated - I don't want to shut down the server without finding out what was actually going on...